# OnNavigatedFrom() vrs OnNavigatedTo() in Windows App

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone

I saw this while surfing about Windows 10 apps and Life cycle, can anybody put some more light on this topic, a illustration with an example will delightful.

> *On Windows Phone, OnNavigatedFrom() is called when the app is suspended. OnNavigatedTo() is not called when the app is resumed.*

Comment: Please explain what exactly is unclear. When an app is suspended, `OnNavigatedFrom()` will be called...

Comment: I am very new for windows developing, I'm not able to understand how to use OnNavigatedFrom() in my code.

Comment: I know I need to apply it, the logic being - I will disable the Toolbars back button if it comes on Home Screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**OnNavigatedFrom** It's override void so you can use it by writing `override` in your .cs page ..

This event will be fired -invoked- when you're leaving the page .. and before navigating from it ..

**OnNavigatedTo** Will be fired -invoked- when you arrive to the page .

Comment: While studying Template 10 I have used OnNavigatedFrom and OnNavigatedTo in ViewModel.cs File where the class extends  ViewModelBase. Can anyone share A code for different Scenarios ? For example in our .cs Page as @Nasser said above.

Comment: Sorry It was public override Task OnNavigatedFromAsync(IDictionary<string, object> state, bool suspending)
{}